# List of lists by unique coordinates

Tags: r, list

I have a data frame like the one below. I want to collapse it, though, so that each unique coordinate is a list of its SubIDs.

```
       subID                  latlon
1  S20298920 29.2178694, -94.9342990
2  S35629295 26.7063982, -80.7168961
3  S35844314 26.7063982, -80.7168961
4  S35833936 26.6836236, -80.3512144
7  S30634757 42.4585456, -76.5146989
8  S35834082 26.4330582, -80.9416786
9  S35857972 26.4330582, -80.9416786
10 S35833885 26.7063982, -80.7168961
```

So, here, I want (26.7063982, -80.7168961) to be a list containing (S35629295, S35844314), and (29.2178694, -94.9342990) to be a list containing just (S20298920). I think a list of lists is what makes most sense.

Comment: What is the type of the `latlon` column, or are there really two columns there?

Comment: Either or, actually. Right now it's a single column, latlon, which is of class `character`, but I also have (not shown) that same info split up into two columns, `lat`, `lon`. Thanks.

Comment: `tidyr::nest(df, subID)` maybe, though technically that makes a list column of data frames. To just use vectors, with dplyr, `df %>% group_by(latlon) %>% summarise_all(list)` or in base, `aggregate(subID ~ latlon, df, list)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `aggregate`:

```
out <- aggregate(data=df,subID~latlon,FUN = function(t) list(sort(paste(t))))
```

Since your data set is large and cumbersome, the sample code below uses watered down data which is easier to read.

```
out <- aggregate(data=df,name~ID,FUN = function(t) list(sort(paste(t))))
out
  ID          name
1  1 apple, orange
2  2        orange
3  3 apple, orange
```

**Data:**

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c(1,1,2,3,3),
                 name=c('apple', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'apple'))
```

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

```
   with(data,tapply(subID,latlon,as.list))
```

output:

```
$`26.4330582 -80.9416786`
$`26.4330582 -80.9416786`[[1]]
[1] "S35834082"

$`26.4330582 -80.9416786`[[2]]
[1] "S35857972"


$`26.6836236 -80.3512144`
$`26.6836236 -80.3512144`[[1]]
[1] "S35833936"
   :
   :
   :
```

data:

```
 data=read.table(text="subID latlon
 S20298920 '29.2178694 -94.9342990'
 S35629295 '26.7063982 -80.7168961'
 S35844314 '26.7063982 -80.7168961'
 S35833936 '26.6836236 -80.3512144'
 S30634757 '42.4585456 -76.5146989'
 S35834082 '26.4330582 -80.9416786'
 S35857972 '26.4330582 -80.9416786'
 S35833885 '26.7063982 -80.7168961' ",h=T,stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the tidyverse, you can either use `tidyr::nest`, which will nest data frames:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data_frame(subID = c("S20298920", "S35629295", "S35844314", "S35833936", "S30634757", "S35834082", "S35857972", "S35833885"), 
                 latlon = c("29.2178694, -94.934299", "26.7063982, -80.7168961", "26.7063982, -80.7168961", "26.6836236, -80.3512144", "42.4585456, -76.5146989", "26.4330582, -80.9416786", "26.4330582, -80.9416786", "26.7063982, -80.7168961"))

df %>% nest(subID)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#>                    latlon             data
#>                     <chr>           <list>
#> 1  29.2178694, -94.934299 <tibble [1 x 1]>
#> 2 26.7063982, -80.7168961 <tibble [3 x 1]>
#> 3 26.6836236, -80.3512144 <tibble [1 x 1]>
#> 4 42.4585456, -76.5146989 <tibble [1 x 1]>
#> 5 26.4330582, -80.9416786 <tibble [2 x 1]>
```

or just summarize with `list` to make a list column of vectors:

```r
df %>% 
    group_by(latlon) %>% 
    summarise_all(list)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#>                    latlon     subID
#>                     <chr>    <list>
#> 1 26.4330582, -80.9416786 <chr [2]>
#> 2 26.6836236, -80.3512144 <chr [1]>
#> 3 26.7063982, -80.7168961 <chr [3]>
#> 4  29.2178694, -94.934299 <chr [1]>
#> 5 42.4585456, -76.5146989 <chr [1]>
```