# Concatenate elements of list to specific format in new column in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, concatenation, paste

I have latlon coordinates with associated "subID"s. I want to make a new column in this data frame where each subID has been pasted into html format. See below:

my data:

```
                   latlon                                   subID
1 25.4034735, -80.5586135 c("S35858790", "S35858833", "S35924843")
2 26.4330582, -80.9416786              c("S35834082", "S35857972")
3 26.452893, -80.979942                                  S35686789
4 29.3339241, -94.7480679              c("S20299537", "S20300308")
```

What I want to see in the first row of the new column (scroll to right):

```
<a href = http://www.SomeUrl.com/S35858790>S35858790</a><a href = http://www.SomeUrl.com/S35858833>S35858833</a><a href = http://www.SomeUrl.com/S35924843>S35924843</a>
```

And the third row should just have:

```
<a href = http://www.SomeUrl.com/S35686789>S35686789</a>
```

The subID column could be lists of up to or over 100 subID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not too different from [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47958679/list-of-lists-by-unique-coordinates/47958780#47958780).  Again, we can use the base R function `aggregate`, this time using `paste` to build the anchor tags you want to use:

```
a_start <- '<a href = http://www.SomeUrl.com/'
a_end <- '</a>'
out <- aggregate(data=df,subID~latlon,FUN = function(t) sort(paste0(a_start, t, '>', t, a_end, collapse="")))
```

### Demo

Even though our custom aggregate function sorts on the entire anchor tag, it should still sort correctly, as the content leading up to the first `subID` is identical for everything.

Comment: This is great, thank you. I would not have been able to figure this out by referencing my previous question, thanks for your help. Is it possible to return the number of subIDs at each loc, using this method? The FUN =  part of this solution is somewhat confusing to me. Thanks.

Comment: @Heliornis You might want to ask a new question, because it is different than this one.  For counting, I would probably use the `dplyr` library.

Comment: I actually figured it out by doing this: `final$nlists = aggregate(data=df,subID~latlon,FUN = function(t) list(sort(n_distinct(t))))`

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `tapply` although this gives you a vector.

```
funfun=function(x)paste0("<a href = http://www.SomeUrl.com/",x,">",x,"</a>",collapse = "")
with(data,tapply(subID,latlon,funfun))
```